# Magento2 : not able to unselect all option of custom multi select attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

In Magento2, it was not possible to unselect and save all multiselect attribute values for a product in earlier versions.  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7687 mentioned this issue. I was not able to unselect all option of custom multi select attribute. I searched and found that need to use `<can_be_select>1</<can_be_select>` inside field (for example, multiselect) in system.xml.
But still in latest version, this issue is occurred for a few cases.

Comment: It works on vendor\magento\module-payment\etc\adminhtml\system.xml. 
It also works on custom module too. If showInStore is used for multiselect and its 's showInStore is not specified, can_be_empty doesn't work at my end. If showInStore is removed from multiselect field in this case, can_be_empty works.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean a custom attribute - it seems a magento bug: [magento bugtracker](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7687)
If the question about the system config field - you should add `can_be_empty` to field definition in the etc/adminhtml/system.xml

`<field>
   ....
   <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
   ...
</field>`

Comment: but i want to know in which core modules's sitemap.xml i have to do change

Comment: sitemap.xml? Are you mean the system.xml? If your question about your own custom field  -  you must know the path to own extension, if not - write the field title.

Comment: no i did not make any extension. but i think i have to do this changing in any core files's sitemap.xml